# Cant add Famono to meteor app

Tags: meteor, famono

Trying to add Famono to my Meteor app, but it ain't working out..

```
$ mrt add famono
$ mrt
```

Gives:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Starting your app...
Ensure dependencies...
 Famono:  Warning, could not load library namespace "famous-polyfills" file: xxx/.meteor/.famono-repos/.famous-polyfills
 Famono:  Could not resolve namespace "famous-polyfills"
=> Started your app.   

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

In file `client/main.js`:

```
require('famous-polyfills');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a more complete answer is to say, look at the latest famono example which shows how famous has changed how dependencies are incorporated into your project.  require() is no longer used.

```
 // Rig some famo.us deps
famousPolyfills;
famous.core.famous;
```

See the latest example: https://github.com/raix/Meteor-famono

Comment: This is a more complete answer indeed.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

With Meteor 1.0, I used  `meteor add raix:famono` .
`mrt` is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the way to require deps changed to:

```
famousPolyfills;
famous.core.famous;
```